# removing characters off the end of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

i am displaying prices of graphics cards from newegg using web scraping. On some of the text i scrape there is unwanted text after the price that gets scraped too. what is the most efficient way to only display the text of the price nothing more.

```
price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})
price = price_container[0].text
if len(price) > 7:
```

the prices(bit i want to keep) are never more than 7 characters long so i thought i could remove the unwanted text using this if statement but im not sure how because each price has different length of unwanted text after it.

Comment: Please show some example of the prices as you scraped them as well as what you expect to be the outcome for each.

Comment: use regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'\$([\d.]+)', price)
if m:
    print(m.group(0)) # to include the dollar sign
    print(m.group(1)) # the amount without the dollar sign
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a regular expression.

Or take a string and extract the numbers from it.
Example:

```
[float(p) for p in price.split() if p.isdigit()] # Will give you an array of the numbers in the string. You can then join them back together.
```

Perhaps not exactly what you are looking for, but hopefully will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(price) > 7:
    price = price[:-1] #This will reasign the string/list to a string/list with all the characters except for the last one.
```